# Database Name not being included in the HREF of imported files in File Resource

Tags: html, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I imported some HTML, JS and image files into Resources->Files of my database.

In the index file, I have:

```html
<base href = "/client/hd">
<img src= "/client/hd/images/imagefile.png">
```

But upon checking the image source, it's accessing the URL below:

http://his90/client/hd/images/imagefile.png excluding the location of database  and database name (ex. /fi20/fi20test.nsf)

It should be http://his90/fi20/fi20test.nsf/client/hd/images/imagefile.png

May I ask for a solution for this? HTML files are just imported in the Resource, no forms or views were created.

Answer (score 1):

That is because you start the link URL with a /. That will start at te root of the web server. If you remove it, the link URL will start from your current location, and (assuming that the index file has the URL http://his90/fi20/fi20test.nsf/index.html) you should get the correct link URL.
You can also create a substitution rule for the internet site (using Domino Administrator, under Configuration, Web, Internet Sites). You then substitute / with /fi20/fi20test.nsf/ and it should also work.
Talk to your administrator about which is the proper way in your specific case.

Also, assuming you add the image as an image resource called imagefile.png, the URL should be just http://his90/fi20/fi20test.nsf/imagefile.png, no file structure. 
What I sometimes do is to create web substitution rules for /images/, /pages/ and /agents/ to all point to the .nsf file itself. Then in the HTML code (and Javascript) I can reference the different resources with /images/imagefile.png or /agents/getUserList.json, etc.  Makes the code much easier to read and understand.

Comment: Hi @Karl-Henry, I tried that one too but the link is referring to this, assuming that the reference for index is the one below.

http://his90/fi20/fi20test.nsf/client/hd/main/index.html

http://his90/fi20/fi20test.nsf/client/hd/main/client/hd/images/imagefile.png

Comment: What is the URL of the page you are on, where the image is supposed to show up?
And what is the exact filename of the image resource in the .nsf file?

Comment: I just added the /fi20/fi20test.nsf to all the src and hrefs. Thank you still, Karl.